# Bluetooth headset for Lenovo Thinkpad T420

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad, headphones

I want to buy a headset which could connect wirelessly with [Lenovo Thinkpad T420](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t420). I want to know if *any* bluetooth headset is compatible with it, or whether there is some technical specification I should look out for to check for compatibility.

I have browsed through the options listed on their site [here](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/web/LenovoPortal/en_US/catalog.workflow:show-category-with-items?ftype=acc&category-id=C81C5BB51B21465D96C353CC4CEF4801&tabname=&filter=Type_1#top), but they are too expensive and I prefer to opt for something available closer home (in India), if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that supports [HSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Headset_Profile_.28HSP.29) should work with it, or [A2DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) if you want listen-only.